# system.log to so many error message

Tags: xml, magento-1.9.2.0

my magento shopping mall is so many error comes up 
what problem...? and cpu28~27% possession..this is normality ?
please tell me !

this is my systemp.log

```
2016-01-29T00:09:03+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:09:19+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:09:44+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:09:55+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:10:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T00:10:11+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:10:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T00:10:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T00:18:10+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:18:17+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:18:21+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:18:49+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:18:52+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:18:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T00:18:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T00:19:18+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T00:19:50+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:22:55+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:22:59+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:23:04+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:55:32+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T00:55:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T00:55:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T00:56:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T00:56:39+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T01:20:58+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T01:21:02+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T01:23:56+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T01:24:01+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T01:26:58+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T01:59:40+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T01:59:43+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:00:15+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:00:17+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T02:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T02:03:53+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:03:56+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:04:52+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:09:13+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:17:39+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:17:44+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:17:53+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:18:02+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:18:28+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:40:21+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:40:27+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:40:34+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:41:10+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /var/www/html/magento/index.php:80
</pre>
2016-01-29T02:43:00+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:44:47+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:45:49+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:46:28+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:46:37+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:46:40+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:47:11+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:50:21+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:50:25+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T02:50:29+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:00:36+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:00:40+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:00:45+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:00:48+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:00:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: fieldString  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/community/VES/PdfPro/Model/Communication/Method/Post.php on line 27
2016-01-29T03:02:13+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:02:16+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:02:27+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:03:13+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:03:17+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:04:17+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:04:32+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:04:48+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:04:52+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:06:02+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:08:59+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:09:03+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:09:08+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:09:18+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:19:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:41:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T03:41:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T03:41:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T05:35:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T05:35:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T05:35:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-30T14:30:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 161
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any deal with ves_pdfpro module? Looks like it triggers the errors. Thy to disable it via app/etc/modules/ves_pdfpro.xml file. Just rename it, for example. If there is a problem, we will investigate further.

Comment: delete ves_pdfpro... but not a resolve

Comment: 2016-01-29T05:35:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T05:35:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-30T14:30:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 161

Comment: @이시우, The errors occur on the all of the page or on some spacial ones? Does the module deleting influence on the CPU ?